# Send code to scheme interpreter from info buffer

Tags: emacs, scheme, sicp

I want to study SICP in my Emacs. I've installed MIT Scheme, Emacs 24 and downloaded sicp info (using this guide http://www.pchristensen.com/blog/articles/setting-up-and-using-emacs-infomode/). Now I'm able to run scheme interpreter in dedicated buffer(M-x run-scheme), but I get the following error when I try to send one of define expressions from *info* buffer (C-x C-e):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function define)
  (define (abs x) (cond ((> x 0) x) ((= x 0) 0) ((< x 0) (- x))))
  eval((define (abs x) (cond ((> x 0) x) ((= x 0) 0) ((< x 0) (- x)))) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

Looks like Emacs is trying to execute this code with Lisp interpreter. As workaround for this issue now I open scheme buffer (*.scm file), copy code to it from info, and them execute it with C-x C-e. But I want to execute it directly from info buffer. How can I setup this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press `(C-x C-e)` in info mode Emacs is invoking `eval-last-sexp` because that is what the key combination is bound to in `info-mode`

What is `(C-x C-e)` bound to in `scheme-mode`? You can find out using `(C-h c)`? You can bind some other key combination to that function in `info` mode and use that key combination.

Note that info mode is **read-only**. If the scheme-eval function inserts the results in current buffer you will need a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run a different function, so try this:

```
(define-key Info-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-e") 'lisp-eval-defun)
```